# Something like publish notes in a webpage

Tags: python, django, feed

I'm building a site where I publish a notice and it appear in one webpage but my code dosen't return the objects. I post my code then:

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Contenidos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from granada.models import Contenidos

def contenidos(request):
    contenido_list = Contenidos.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'contenidos.html', {'contenido_list' : contenido_list})
```

contenidos.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Contenidos {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2> contenidos </h2>

    {% for contenido in contenido_list %}
        <h3>
            {{ contenido_list.title }}
        </h3>
        <p>{{ contenido_list.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the wrong object in your loop, `contenidos` instead of `contenido`.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Contenidos {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2> contenidos </h2>

    {% for contenido in contenidos %}
        <h3>
            {{ contenido.title }}  {# was contenidos.title #}
        </h3>
        <p>{{ contenido.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the output of `{% print contenidos %}` and `{% print contenido %}`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean to say. Now the for doesn't return anything and should return the title and content from de database

Comment: If you add the tags `{% print contenidos %}` and `{%print contenido $}` (last one in the loop) to your template, what do you see on the page? It should post debug information about a queryset object or a Contenido object.

Comment: It returns: Could not parse the remainder: ' contenidos' from 'print contenidos'

Comment: Hm, that's strange. What appears when you use `{{ contenidos }}`?

Comment: ok whe i write {{ contenido }} return all the objectas but when i write {{ contenido.title }} it doesnt return anything and if i write the for nothingh happend

Comment: Wait, I see you updated your question and are now passing the list of objects as `contenido`, while in your template you're using `contenidos` as your list and `contenido` as the individual objects. You should really make a clear, consistent distinction between the two. FOr the sake of clarity you might even want to use `contenido_list` and `contenido`.

Comment: OK I edited it and now i clear is clarity, i need to improve my clear when i write code